# AVR ATmega32 - C - Gets stuck in function call

Tags: avr, c

I have had lots of problems trying to get a piece of firmware to work which has worked fine earlier, and is working on a copy of the board I'm having problems with.  I've narrowed in down to the following (at least to start with):

This piece of code works:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{   
   // LEDs - initial setting
   DDRC |= 0x03;                // LEDs on pins PC0 and PC1 
   PORTC &= ~(1<<0);             // LED0 OFF
   PORTC |= (1<<1);             // LED1 ON

   DDRD |= 0x30;    // PD4..5 OUT
   TCCR1A = 0xE2;   //0b11100010 (Set OC1A + Clear OC1B on compare match, )
   TCCR1B = 0x19;   //0b00011001 (WGM13:10 = 0b1110 => Fast PWM Mode, TOP = ICR1, CS12:0 = 001 => Use IO clock, no prescaling)
   OCR1A = 18;
   OCR1B = 18;      //  18 / 8000000 =  2.25 us (Output compare match value (OC1A->HIGH, OC1B->LOW)
   ICR1 = 757;      // 757 / 8000000 = 94.625us (TOP value for timer1)

   // Loop blinks LED0..1 alternately
   while(1)
   {
       PORTC = PORTC ^ 0x03;
       _delay_ms(250);
   }
}
```

It starts the timer and outputs the pulse with the specified timing, and enters the blinking LED loop.

However, this code fails:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void pulse_init(void)
{   
   DDRD |= 0x30;    // PD4..5 OUT
   TCCR1A = 0xE2;   //0b11100010 (Set OC1A + Clear OC1B on compare match, )
   TCCR1B = 0x19;   //0b00011001 (WGM13:10 = 0b1110 => Fast PWM Mode, TOP = ICR1, CS12:0 = 001 => Use IO clock, no prescaling)
   OCR1A = 18;
   OCR1B = 18;      //  18 / 8000000 =  2.25 us (Output compare match value (OC1A->HIGH, OC1B->LOW)
   ICR1 = 757;      // 757 / 8000000 = 94.625us (TOP value for timer1)
}


int main(void)
{   
   // LEDs - initial setting
   DDRC |= 0x03;                // LEDs on pins PC0 and PC1 
   PORTC &= ~(1<<0);            // LED0 OFF
   PORTC |= (1<<1);         // LED1 ON

   pulse_init();

   // Loop blinks LED0..1 alternately
   while(1)
   {
       PORTC = PORTC ^ 0x03;
       _delay_ms(250);
   }
}
```

...it's just the same statements as before, moved to the pulse_init() function. When I upload this code the timer is set up correctly and the output pulse is OK, but the program never starts blinking the LEDs on PC0..1.

Any ideas? It's not just this function, this is part of a bigger program with other initalization functions and it seems whenever the program enters a function separate from the main loop it fails to return to main. I am not so familiar with C and how it works on the function block level. I am using Atmel Studio 7 now with the following compiler options:

```
-x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.1.130\include"  -O1 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -g2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -mmcu=atmega32 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.1.130\gcc\dev\atmega32" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"
```

but I had the same problems with avrdude. I also tried reading the full binary from the working board and writing it to the board I'm working on. It should communicate with PC over a USB-to-serial but it doesn't work. When I power up the board it spews a few kilobytes on nonsense to the serial (the same nonsense every time, though) and then freezes, i.e. doesn't send the regular "Waiting for command" message or reply to any commands.

The chip is Atmega32L8AU, 8MHz external crystal, `LFUSE=0xFF`, `HFUSE=0x99`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Codewise, there's nothing wrong with what you've done. I can't see any obvious problem, a single function called once shouldn't be a problem unless you have zero size for the stack. If I understood your question correctly and it works on one board but not on another, I would suspect hardware rather than software.

Comment: Might be incorrect stack setup. Triple-check that the correct part ist used when *linking* the project.

Comment: @RogerRowland I haven't actually tried compiling and programming the board that is already working with my updated code for fear of bricking it. What I have done is read the hex file off that board and program the board I'm working on with it, and it doesn't work. I suspect hardware problems as well, but I can't for the life of me find any... Maybe the chip is damaged. I just wanted to get a second opinion on the coding aspect.

Comment: @TurboJ : The linker options: `-Wl,-Map="$(OutputFileName).map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega32 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.1.130\gcc\dev\atmega32" ` It's the correct part number at least, but for the other parameters I'm not so familiar with them.

Comment: Could you compile both sets of code and upload the resulting `*.elf` files to a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: @SnorreO. - the resolution of your question should not be edited into your question, as a question here is not "resolved" until an answer is accepted. If none of the existing answers contain your solution, you can post your own answer explaining it.  Your theory, while not impossible does seem rather unlikely however.

Comment: I have had a similar problem.
Ticking off a fuse bit EXTENDED.M103C helped.

Comment: ( Following [this comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277180/avr-atmega32-c-gets-stuck-in-function-call#comment634555_277180) from *[Chris Stratton](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2246/chris-stratton)* above, and due to someone trying to answer the question meaning they didn't realise it had been solved, I have moved the OP's stated solution into an actual *answer*,)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the warnings in your compiler (if any) ?

Your problem seems to me like there is an issue with function decleration, perhaps. Can you try to declare the function first on top of main and put function body at the bottom of main.c? Does the issue persists?

Also, have you tried debugger of atmel studio? If you haven't yet, please try and execute step by step. Observe the registers and see how they change.

One more question, can you do a simple error checking/tracking? For example,

```
#define F_CPU 8000000

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

uint8_t PROG_STATE = 0;
void Send_to_PC(uint8_t DATA);

void pulse_init(void)
{   
   PROG_STATE = 3;
   Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
   DDRD |= 0x30;    // PD4..5 OUT
   TCCR1A = 0xE2;   //0b11100010 (Set OC1A + Clear OC1B on compare match, )
   TCCR1B = 0x19;   //0b00011001 (WGM13:10 = 0b1110 => Fast PWM Mode, TOP = ICR1, CS12:0 = 001 => Use IO clock, no prescaling)
   OCR1A = 18;
   OCR1B = 18;      //  18 / 8000000 =  2.25 us (Output compare match value (OC1A->HIGH, OC1B->LOW)
   ICR1 = 757;      // 757 / 8000000 = 94.625us (TOP value for timer1)
}


int main(void)
{   
   PROG_STATE = 1;
   Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
   // LEDs - initial setting
   DDRC |= 0x03;                // LEDs on pins PC0 and PC1 
   PORTC &= ~(1<<0);            // LED0 OFF
   PORTC |= (1<<1);         // LED1 ON
   PROG_STATE = 2;
   Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
   pulse_init();
   PROG_STATE = 4;
   Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
   // Loop blinks LED0..1 alternately
   while(1)
   {
       PROG_STATE = 5;
       Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
       PORTC = PORTC ^ 0x03;
       _delay_ms(250);
       PROG_STATE = 6;
       Send_to_PC(PROG_STATE);
   }
}

void Send_to_PC(uint8 DATA){
//RS232 OR I2C etc
}
```

You get the idea. If you do something like this, then you can observe the state of your program live (apart from the debugger).

Edit:

Added Atmega32/32L internal block diagram

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you mean *declaration*?  The C language doesn't define any "function initialization", although an actual implementation may have steps needed before calling a function, such as copying the code segment from flash to RAM.

Comment: Yes, decleration. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Also, I wanted to talk about the decleration because perhaps the compiled code misses something about calling a function and its return value? And yes, as far as I know, the functions are copied from program memory to RAM before execution. But I think the program memory is faulty. If there is an issue with the memory->RAM circuit, wouldn't most of his code run erroneously?

Comment: Many microcontrollers run code directly from flash... but if his does copy to RAM first, and the linker wasn't aware of the address the code would be copied to, then the function addresses encoded in call instructions might become incorrect.  (There's also "position independent code" for this).  Errors on the memory bus would surely affect nearly all the code, but a single bit error inside the RAM to where the code was copied would be just as localized as a single bit error in program flash.

Comment: I've added the internal block diagram of his chip from datasheet. It seems that the code is run directly from flash (albeit parts of it being loaded to SRAM). I think you are right about this. I agree on your point with single bit error. If some functions other than main work and some doesn't, perhaps his memory/register in sram at those locations are faulty, then.

Comment: @Maximus: I tried your suggestions to no help. No compiler warnings, even when I'm using -Wall -Wextra and -pedantic as you can see. Forward declaration of the function didn't change things. The LED blinking was sort of my program tracking. Just for fun though I initialized the USART in the main loop and were able to send bytes over serial OK by writing the UDR register.

Comment: The problem gets more sinister: I am able to enter and return from functions of the type `int dummy(int a) {return a;}` and `void dummy(void){}` but not my `pulse_init()`. However if I comment out all but one line of the `pulse_init()` contents it will return, as long as this line is not the `DDRD |= 0x30;`assignment. That is, if I leave the first line in, or any 2 of the others, the function never returns. None of the statements in the function pose a problem if they are in the main loop.I am leaning towards faulty memory, I think I will replace the chip now to rule this out.

Comment: @BenVoigt, @ Maximus: I changed the chip, and it worked! Must have been a faulty SRAM area as you suggested. Thank you all for all your help :) PS I'm not sure about how to proceed in the stackexchange-correct way now, should I mark this one as the answer or make and accept a new answer referring Maximus' comment about memory fault?

Comment: @SnorreO. Wow, man! Well, I suppose the SRAM could be faulty. If flash data was corrupt, wouldn't it become appearant when your IDE verifies the uploaded HEX? I think it could also be a fault on the program memory->SRAM/GPR line as well (data gets corrupt during transmission). But then it would be random so you wouldn't have done anything at all?I would suggest that you read the SRAM/GPR in debug mode, perhaps. I bet that there is a corrupt byte in there that tells the CPU to do an undefined operation so the CPU quits to the last verified stack in the program memory. (Just a guess)

Comment: @SnorreO.: I've been working with AVR 8-bit controllers for 10+ years and never had a "faulty SRAM". I would classify this as highly unlikely. Are you able to change the controller back and verify that is does not work with the EXACT same code. Make also sure that the fuse bits are configured identically.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I suggest the auther to do SRAM march test. He can send byte to individual sram cells and read it afterwards. If there is a mismatch between the sent and received bytes, then there must be an SRAM fault. He can do the same for CPU registers.

Answer (score 1):

Statement from the OP - *[Snorre O.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/59965/snorre-o)*:

> SOLVED - The firmware works after changing the AVR chip. Turns out to be a faulty memory area in the SRAM or possibly something wrong with the SRAM/GPR bus. This was suggested {in comments to} [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277180/avr-atmega32-c-gets-stuck-in-function-call/277215#277215) {...}

---

<sub>(This question was reported solved by the OP, however no answer stating the the solution was written and accepted to make this clear. The solution was added into the question and as a comment - instead of being written an answer, as should be done - and we still have people thinking the topic is unsolved. Therefore I have copied the solution given by the OP into this as an actual *answer*. I have applied the approach explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to post someone else's content as an answer. I have set the answer to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't *my* solution.)</sub>